# 'module' object is not callable. Error while AI file execution

Tags: python, openai-api

I am trying to make an AI using openai and I have ran into a problem. My python version in 3.8.3

Here is my code:

```
fileopen = open("Data\\Api.txt","r")
API = fileopen.read()
fileopen.close()

import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv

openai.api_key = API
load_dotenv()
completion = openai.Completion()

def ReplyBrain(question,chat_log=None):
    FileLog = openai("","r")
    chat_log_template = FileLog.read()
    FileLog.close()

    if chat_log is None:
        chat_log = chat_log_template

    prompt = f'{chat_log}You : {question}\nJarvis : '
    response = completion.create(
        model = "text-davinci-002",
        prompt = prompt,
        temperature = 0.5,
        max_tokens = 60,
        top_p = 0.3,
        frequency_penalty = 0.5,
        presence_penalty = 0)
    answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    chat_log_template_update = chat_log_template + f"\nYou : {question} \nJarvis : {answer}"
    FileLog = open("","w")
    FileLog.write(chat_log_template_update)
    FileLog.close()
    return answer

while True:
    kk = input("Enter :")
    ReplyBrain(kk)
```

This is the error code which I recieved-

```
line 13, in ReplyBrain
    FileLog = openai("","r")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this

```
import openai
...
    FileLog = openai("","r")
```

and complained of a "not callable" diagnostic.

Well, the module is not callable.
It is unclear what you were hoping
that pair of args might accomplish.

If you refer to their documentation
and to the [OpenAI Cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Backtranslation_of_SQL_queries.py),
you will find numerous examples
of how to correctly invoke code within
that module.

Comment: Can you tell me what to change please because I am new to coding.

Comment: Refer to their documentation and to the OpenAI Cookbook, where you will find numerous examples of how to correctly invoke code within that module.

Answer (score 0):

After adding openai API key Try this :

```
def ReplyBrain(question, chat_log=None):
file_path = "chat_log.txt" #make sure the file exists in the same directory
if chat_log is None:
    with open(file_path, "r") as Filelog: 
        chat_log_template = Filelog.read()
    chat_log = chat_log_template.strip()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).